# C# WPF DataGrid bind XML

Tags: c#, wpf

This XML is deserialized properly from a website and returned as a class object. For example, I can call balanceResponse.accountId in my method and it will display a value, so I know it is working. I use the same process for other web requests and have not had an issue binding them to a WPF DataGrid.

What am I doing wrong in the XAML? It is not displaying any values.

The XML class was generated with special copy paste in Visual Studio by the way.

XAML:

```
       <DataGrid x:Name="accountBalanceGrid" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding BalanceResponse}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

              <DataGrid.Columns>
                       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account ID" Binding="{Binding accountId}" > 
                       </DataGridTextColumn>
              </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Method:

```
     private async Task PopulateAccount()
    {
        BalanceResponse balanceResponse = new BalanceResponse();
        balanceResponse = await api.GetAccountBalance();
        accountBalanceGrid.DataContext = balanceResponse;
    }
```

Balance Response Class:

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
public partial class BalanceResponse
{

    private string accountIdField;
    private string accountTypeField;
    private string optionLevelField;
    private string accountDescriptionField;
    private string quoteModeField;
    private string dayTraderStatusField;
    private string accountModeField;
    private BalanceResponseCash cashField;
    private BalanceResponseComputed computedField;
    private BalanceResponseMargin marginField;

    public string accountId
    {
        get {return this.accountIdField;}
        set {this.accountIdField = value;}
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string accountType
    {
        get{return this.accountTypeField;}
        set{this.accountTypeField = value;}
    }
    public string optionLevel
    {
        get{return this.optionLevelField;}
        set{this.optionLevelField = value;}
    }
    public string accountDescription
    {
        get{return this.accountDescriptionField;}
        set{this.accountDescriptionField = value;}
    }
    public string quoteMode
    {
        get{return this.quoteModeField;}
        set{this.quoteModeField = value;}
    }
    public string dayTraderStatus
    {
        get{return this.dayTraderStatusField;}
        set{this.dayTraderStatusField = value;}
    }
    public string accountMode
    {
        get{return this.accountModeField;}
        set{this.accountModeField = value;}
    }
    public BalanceResponseCash Cash
    {
        get{return this.cashField;}
        set{this.cashField = value;}
    }
    public BalanceResponseComputed Computed
    {
        get{return this.computedField;}
        set{this.computedField = value;}
    }

    public BalanceResponseMargin Margin
    {
        get{return this.marginField;}
        set{this.marginField = value;}
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class BalanceResponseCash
{
    private decimal fundsForOpenOrdersCashField;
    private decimal moneyMktBalanceField;
    public decimal fundsForOpenOrdersCash
    {
        get{return this.fundsForOpenOrdersCashField;}
        set{this.fundsForOpenOrdersCashField = value;}
    }
    public decimal moneyMktBalance
    {
        get{return this.moneyMktBalanceField;}
        set{this.moneyMktBalanceField = value;}
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class BalanceResponseComputed
{

    private decimal cashAvailableForInvestmentField;
    private decimal netCashField;
    private decimal cashBalanceField;
    private decimal settledCashForInvestmentField;
    private decimal unSettledCashForInvestmentField;
    private decimal fundsWithheldFromPurchasePowerField;
    private decimal fundsWithheldFromWithdrawalField;
    private decimal marginBuyingPowerField;
    private decimal cashBuyingPowerField;
    private decimal dtMarginBuyingPowerField;
    private decimal dtCashBuyingPowerField;
    private decimal shortAdjustBalanceField;
    private decimal regtEquityField;
    private decimal regtEquityPercentField;
    private decimal accountBalanceField;
    public decimal cashAvailableForInvestment
    {
        get{return this.cashAvailableForInvestmentField;}
        set{this.cashAvailableForInvestmentField = value;}
    }
    public decimal netCash
    {
        get{return this.netCashField;}
        set{this.netCashField = value;}
    }
    public decimal cashBalance
    {
        get{return this.cashBalanceField;}
        set{this.cashBalanceField = value;}
    }
    public decimal settledCashForInvestment
    {
        get{return this.settledCashForInvestmentField;}
        set{this.settledCashForInvestmentField = value;}
    }
    public decimal unSettledCashForInvestment
    {
        get{return this.unSettledCashForInvestmentField;}
        set{this.unSettledCashForInvestmentField = value;}
    }
    public decimal fundsWithheldFromPurchasePower
    {
        get{return this.fundsWithheldFromPurchasePowerField;}
        set{this.fundsWithheldFromPurchasePowerField = value;}
    }
    public decimal fundsWithheldFromWithdrawal
    {
        get{return this.fundsWithheldFromWithdrawalField;}
        set{this.fundsWithheldFromWithdrawalField = value;}
    }
    public decimal marginBuyingPower
    {
        get{return this.marginBuyingPowerField;}
        set{this.marginBuyingPowerField = value;}
    }
    public decimal cashBuyingPower
    {
        get{return this.cashBuyingPowerField;}
        set{this.cashBuyingPowerField = value;}
    }
    public decimal dtMarginBuyingPower
    {
        get{return this.dtMarginBuyingPowerField;}
        set{this.dtMarginBuyingPowerField = value;}
    }
    public decimal dtCashBuyingPower
    {
        get{return this.dtCashBuyingPowerField;}
        set{this.dtCashBuyingPowerField = value;}
    }
    public decimal shortAdjustBalance
    {
        get{return this.shortAdjustBalanceField;}
        set{this.shortAdjustBalanceField = value;}
    }
    public decimal regtEquity
    {
        get{return this.regtEquityField;}
        set{this.regtEquityField = value;}
    }
    public decimal regtEquityPercent
    {
        get{return this.regtEquityPercentField;}
        set{this.regtEquityPercentField = value;}
    }
    public decimal accountBalance
    {
        get{return this.accountBalanceField;}
        set{this.accountBalanceField = value;}
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class BalanceResponseMargin
{

    private decimal dtCashOpenOrderReserveField;
    private decimal dtMarginOpenOrderReserveField;
    public decimal dtCashOpenOrderReserve
    {
        get{return this.dtCashOpenOrderReserveField;}
        set{this.dtCashOpenOrderReserveField = value;}
    }
    public decimal dtMarginOpenOrderReserve
    {
        get{return this.dtMarginOpenOrderReserveField;}
        set{this.dtMarginOpenOrderReserveField = value;}
    }
}
```

XML Example:

```
<BalanceResponse>
   <accountId>83564979</accountId>
   <accountType>PDT_ACCOUNT</accountType>
   <optionLevel>LEVEL_4</optionLevel>
   <accountDescription>KRITHH TT</accountDescription>
   <quoteMode>6</quoteMode>
   <dayTraderStatus>PDT_MIN_EQUITY_RES_1XK</dayTraderStatus>
   <accountMode>PDT ACCOUNT</accountMode>
   <Cash>
      <fundsForOpenOrdersCash>0</fundsForOpenOrdersCash>
      <moneyMktBalance>0</moneyMktBalance>
   </Cash>
   <Computed>
      <cashAvailableForInvestment>0</cashAvailableForInvestment>
      <netCash>93921.44</netCash>
      <cashBalance>93921.44</cashBalance>
      <settledCashForInvestment>0</settledCashForInvestment>
      <unSettledCashForInvestment>0</unSettledCashForInvestment>
      <fundsWithheldFromPurchasePower>0</fundsWithheldFromPurchasePower>
      <fundsWithheldFromWithdrawal>0</fundsWithheldFromWithdrawal>
      <marginBuyingPower>0</marginBuyingPower>
      <cashBuyingPower>93921.44</cashBuyingPower>
      <dtMarginBuyingPower>0</dtMarginBuyingPower>
      <dtCashBuyingPower>0</dtCashBuyingPower>
      <shortAdjustBalance>0</shortAdjustBalance>
      <regtEquity>0</regtEquity>
      <regtEquityPercent>0</regtEquityPercent>
      <accountBalance>0</accountBalance>
   </Computed>
   <Margin>
      <dtCashOpenOrderReserve>0</dtCashOpenOrderReserve>
      <dtMarginOpenOrderReserve>0</dtMarginOpenOrderReserve>
   </Margin>
</BalanceResponse>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? The `ItemsSource` is supposed to be set or bound to an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: What am I doing wrong in the XAML? It is not displaying any values.

Comment: You set the `DataContext` to a `BalanceResponse` which doesn't seem to have any `BalanceResponse` property that you are trying to bind to. Why would it display any values?

Comment: Where is your collection or enumerable of accounts to begin with?

Comment: I followed the same method that I did with other data. Still new to this. I don't think the XML is a collection, if it had say <BalanceResponse> <Account> ...  </Account> </BalanceResponse> then I think it would be fine, but I suppose I don't know how to go about adding it.

Comment: Try this: `accountBalanceGrid.ItemsSource = new BalanceResponse[1] { balanceResponse  };`

Comment: But why do you want to display a `DataGrid` with only a single `BalanceResponse` object...?

Comment: THAT DID IT! To answer your question, I decided to use WPF for this project, and wanted to use DataGrid's, in case I need to add dropdowns and other design elements to it in the future. DataGrid's just seem the most versatile to me, but then again I'm still learning! Thank you again! I spent the past 4 days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` is supposed to be set or bound to an `IEnumerable`. You set the `DataContext` to a `BalanceResponse` object which doesn't seem to have any `BalanceResponse` property that you are trying to bind to:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding BalanceResponse}"
```

If there is no collection or enumerable of responses, you have to create one yourself:

```
accountBalanceGrid.ItemsSource = new BalanceResponse[1] { balanceResponse };
```